# Is there a loop function for automating data pull request from Google Trends?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-trends

I want to create a loop that helps me to pull data from Google Trends via PyTrends. I need to iterate through a lot of keywords but Google Trends allows only to compare five keywords at the time, hence I need to iterate through the keywords manually and create a `dataframe` in `pandas`. However, it seems something is off.

I get data but my `dataframe` with `pandas` creates the `dataframe` with values that are shifted in different rows and with duplicate "NaN" values.

instead of 62 rows I get 372 rows(with duplicate "NaN").

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
import pandas as pd

pytrend = TrendReq()


kw_list = ['cool', 'fun', 'big','house', 'phone', 'garden']


df1 = pd.DataFrame()

for i in kw_list:
    kw_list = i
    pytrend.build_payload([kw_list], timeframe='2015-10-14 2015-12-14', geo='FR')
    df1 = df1.append(pytrend.interest_over_time())
print(df1.head)
```

I want to have one coherent dataframe, with the columns 'cool', 'fun', 'big','house', 'phone', 'garden' and their respective values in each column on the same row. Like e.g. a dataframe with 62 rows and 6 columns.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably going to lose some rep points because this is an old question (oldish, anyway), but I was struggling with the same problem and I solved it like this:

```
import pytrends
import pandas as pd
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
pytrend = TrendReq()

kw_list = ['cool', 'fun', 'big','house', 'phone', 'garden']
df_gtrends_kw = {}
df_gtrends = pd.DataFrame()

for kw in kw_list:
    pytrend.build_payload(kw_list = [kw], timeframe='today 12-m')
    df_gtrends_kw[kw] = pytrend.interest_by_region(resolution='COUNTRY')

df_gtrends = pd.concat([df_gtrends_kw[key] for key in kw_list], join = 'inner', axis = 1)
```

According to the [official doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/merging.html#set-logic-on-the-other-axes), one has to specify the axes along which one is to glue the dataframes; in this case, the Column names, since the index name is the same for each dataframe.